# How to make TAP adapter accept all traffic form PC?

Tags: networking, openvpn

I'm developing a client application to capture traffic on a PC. I'm using OpenVpn tun/tap adapter. But it dosen't work, when I'm testing application  traffic goes through Wireless LAN adapter. How to make all traffic go through  tun/tap adapter?

```
DWORD active = 1;
DWORD len;
int status = DeviceIoControl(handle, 
    TAP_CONTROL_CODE(6, 0), // TAP_IOCTL_SET_MEDIA_STATUS
    &active,
    sizeof(active),
    &active,
    sizeof(active),
    &len,
    NULL
    );
if(status == 0)
{
    return NULL;
}

int configtun[3] = {0x01000b0a, 0x01000b0a, 0x0000ffff}; // IP, NETWORK, MASK
configtun[0] = inet_addr(ip);
configtun[1] = inet_addr(ip);
char *p = (char*)(configtun+1);
*(p+3) = 0;

status = DeviceIoControl(handle,
TAP_CONTROL_CODE(10, 0), // TAP_IOCTL_CONFIG_TUN
    &configtun,
    sizeof(configtun),
    &configtun,
    sizeof(configtun),//active),
    &len,
    NULL
    );
if(status == 0)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a compilable version of your source code?

Comment: @Gábor https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tpwOoBEH615aGHn6FjWuzdxL49fl9mFS and git  https://github.com/septem776/TunTap/tree/master/TunTapTest